# Icons and manifest.json

Tags: html, browser, service-worker, manifest.json

What are the recommendations on how to deal with icons in [manifest.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json)?

I found this [webpack plugin that generates icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/favicons-webpack-plugin). It generated 37 icons and the corresponding HTML tags.

```html
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">
<meta name="application-name" content="graff">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="@dasnoo/graffity-inferno">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-750x1294.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-1182x2208.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-1242x2148.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons-ce3ab881bd31f1efc59c9c227d8f6b7f/favicon.ico">
```

For optimal results, should I put the icons in my `manifest.json` file **and** HTML `meta` tags? What would having 37 icons achieve that I wouldn't have with say 10 icons (I assume it's more mobile support, but if 3 icons handle 95% of browsers, it effectively achieve nothing)? What are the recommended ones?

This is for a service worker.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're correct, each of those icons is for a different device and often a different version of said device. However, you don't really need 37. To get 37, they generate pixel perfect icons for devices that have much less than 1% market share. You can just provide the nearest match for them and almost no one will even notice. I tend to put browser related icons in the HTML `meta` tags and app related icons in the manifest.

[Here](https://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/new-favicon-package-less-is-more/) is a good post about all of this.

Answer (score 1):

At a baseline, you should be following the structure of the manifest below.  More details can be found on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest).  Though if you run [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) against your PWA, it will ask for another icon sized at 512px.

```
{
    "name": "HackerWeb",
    "short_name": "HackerWeb",
    "start_url": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#fff",
    "description": "A simply readable Hacker News app.",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "images/touch/homescreen48.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/touch/homescreen72.png",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/touch/homescreen96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/touch/homescreen144.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/touch/homescreen168.png",
            "sizes": "168x168",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/touch/homescreen192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "related_applications": [
        {
            "platform": "web"
        },
        {
            "platform": "play",
            "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cheeaun.hackerweb"
        }
    ]
}
```